# div element have wrong viewport

Tags: html, css, debugging, mobile, viewport

This how the page look liike in regular computer:

https://i.imagesup.co/images2/83d44ebd26a8d65586a8dca77544d6ae04f47241.png

And this is the problem in mobile version:
When I try to set the div witdh to 100 precent or 100vw or position this elment , it's like it doesn't fit to the real beginning (right side) and the element think the beginning is somewhere in the middle.
I talk about the second white box ("AboutWhite").
You can see here how it look like: 
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/af732e6868a68765a8abafdadce0ab5049506e4a.png

Why it's different from the the first white box ?

Thank you very much for help !!!

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hover.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="WhiteBox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <img class="img-center" id="img-main" src="http://thestarsetsociety.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/assasn-14li-banner-800x300.jpg" alt="E=MC^2"/>
    <img class="img-center" id="img-below" src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Frainerzitelmann%2Ffiles%2F2019%2F06%2FE0MG76-e1560965378507-1200x1270.jpg" alt="Albert"/>
    <h1>אלברט איינשטיין</h1>
    <h2>פיזיקאי תיאורטי</h2>
   <div id="DivIcons">
     <div id="flex-mobile1">
    <a href="tel:+4917640206387" target="_blank"><img id="MobileHover" class="icons" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thin-line-color-1/21/13-512.png" alt="Moblie Icon"></a>
    <a href="https://www.whatsapp.com/" target="_blank"><img class="icons" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/452/whatsapp.png" alt="What'sapp Icon"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img class="icons" src="https://www.trzcacak.rs/myfile/full/311-3111799_social-media-computer-icons-logo-blue-area-png.png" alt="Instagram Icon"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="flex-mobile2">
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" target="_blank"><img class="icons" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-thin-line-color/21/20-512.png" alt="Email Icon"></a>
    <a href="https://he-il.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img class="icons" src="https://thebrightwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/facebook-icon-blue.png" alt="Facebook Icon"></a>
    <a href="https://www.waze.com/he/livemap" target="_blank"><img class="icons" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-logos-6/512/10-waze-512.png" alt="Waze Icon"></a>
    </div> 
  </div>

   <div id="FirstWhite"></div> <!--Only for Design - White Box-->



 </header>

<article>
  <h3>
    קצת עלי
  </h3>
  <b>
  <p>
      לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם. וסטיבולום אט דולור, קראס אגת לקטוס וואל אאוגו וסטיבולום סוליסי טידום בעליק. 
  </p>
  </b>
  <p>
      לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם. וסטיבולום אט דולור, קראס אגת לקטוס וואל אאוגו וסטיבולום סוליסי טידום בעליק. 
  </p>
  <p>
      לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית. סת אלמנקום ניסי נון ניבאה. דס איאקוליס וולופטה דיאם. וסטיבולום אט דולור, קראס אגת לקטוס וואל אאוגו וסטיבולום סוליסי טידום בעליק. 
  </p>
</article>
<div id="AboutWhite"></div> <!--Only for Design - White Box-->



</body>
</html>
```

Css style:

```
body {
    margin: auto 0;
    direction: rtl;
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

.img-center {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#img-below {
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 8%; 
    width: 8%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 80px;
}

h1 {
    color:#0099ff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom:  120px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 157px;
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;

}

.icons {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: #0099ff 5px solid;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#DivIcons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 170px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;


}

article {
    width: 160px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 455px;
    right: 397px;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
}
```

Css white boxes:

```
#FirstWhite{
    width: 750px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 460px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#AboutWhite {
    width: 200px;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1113px;
    right: 385px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Mobile css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
    #img-main {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #img-below {
        width: 30vw;
        height: 30vh;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    h1, h2 {
        font-size: 7vw;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: 'M PLUS Rounded 1c', sans-serif;
    }

    #flex-mobile1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        right: 120px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #flex-mobile2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        position: relative;
        top: 150px;
        left: 133px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }


    #FirstWhite{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 460px;
        z-index: -1;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #AboutWhite {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
        left: 1000px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try width: 100vw !impotant for #FirstWhite in the max-width:768px media query and see if it will help sort anything out

Comment: @nada Still doesn't work. I can't really understand how it could help.

Comment: Sorry, that was important not impotent, I hope you caught that mistake. Anyway, it was to check if it is really changing the width to 100vw because you have width:750px outside the media query

Comment: I think i was looking at the wrong div, you want help with #AboutWhite right? I have a question, for mobile why do you have the left: 1000px in #AboutWhite?

Comment: @nada Just tried to move it to the right side (didn't work). If you remove this command it doesn't change nothing.  I didn't really get what you said "it was to check if it is really changing the width to 100vw because you have width:750px outside the media query" and I think this the issue. Why i have 750px out of the media query ?

Comment: @nada Just got it. Because I used position in the white boxes css file and if i remove it, it's become finally properly with 100vw. The problem is that I can't give up the position. What can i do and why it's happening ?

Comment: Sorry for delaying. Was away from my phone. I'll open the problem on my pc an take a proper look at it just now

Comment: after playing with it just bit, I think I see where the problem might be. inside the media query, in #AboutWhite, place right: 0px;. Also place article { right: 0px;} in the media query to test and see if it gives you any ideas

Comment: As an aside, I think it would be very helpful for you to learn display grid and flex for future work, it makes thinks more easier to work with, you might even find that with display grid you don't even need to include media queries for some uses anymore.

Comment: @nada Thank you ! It actually work. But how right:0px set this up ? all it's meaning move to left 0 pixels, it's like saying don't change nothing, the element stay in the same position.

Comment: I don't know if I can explain it in a way that makes good sense since I have never read the complete css spec or deeply understand how it works but I'll try to explain to the best of MY understanding. When you position: relative it is sort of like lifting the element up one layer so that it can move freely but still tied to its' paternt's bounds (top, bottom, left, right).By default it is tied to left and top only, if you set right:X it is now tied to left, top, AND right. so right:X is like start at left:X and end at right:X. But I know it is not really like this.It is hard to explain for me

Comment: I hope that makes sense. Visit this link to get started leaning grid, I promise it will help you a lot. https://gridbyexample.com

Comment: node: the left:0px means 0px from its' parents' 100%